# withCredentials dont belong to request header

Tags: angular, http, xmlhttprequest

Using xhr requests in chrome console with and without `withCredentials` xhrField shows the same request header attributes.

How withCredentials is mapped to request header ?

Typescript call  (Angular 2) :

```js
login(username : string, password : string) {
    let data = {username: username, password: password}
    return this.http.post(environment.apiEndpoint + 'login', data, { withCredentials: true })
      .catch((error) => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json());
      });
  }
```

**Note:** It's a cross origin call and I don't recieve cookies even if the server send them (set-cookie header field)

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials):

> The XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials property is a Boolean that indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates. Setting withCredentials has no effect on same-site requests.

It means that on cross-site request, it will add cookies, tls certificates and Authorization header, on same-origin request: nothing. It also allows X-site XHR to set cookies which is not the case usually.

Comment: it must be sent somewhere in the request, I need to find when it's situated in the header so that I can debug it (if it exists or not) using chrom developer tools

Comment: It's written: it puts a `Cookie`, or `Authorization` header or set a tls certificate.

Comment: I am using Angular 2. I need to check if http module sends withCredentials or not. How to get that information

Comment: please edit your question, add the code of your request and tell if the request is made from the same origin or not.

Comment: when I do manual call using console ($.ajax) I receive cookies when I add withcredentials and I don't receive whitout withCredentials. that means there is a problem with my code since it doesn't receive cookies, something like Angular 2 is ignoring withCredentials option